# What is the time complexity of concatenating two vectors in scala?

Tags: scala, vector, collections, time-complexity

Given two vectors of length n and m respectively, what is the time complexity of concatenating them using the `++` operator? For lists, I believe it's O(n+m). Is it any better for vectors? Does any collection in scala have a better concatenation time than O(n+m)?
Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: `Vactor` is persistent, so `O(m)` using `Array.copy`.

Comment: See [collections. Performance Characteristics](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html): `Vector append - eC`, `++` - optimized version of `m appends`.

Comment: see https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4442

Comment: @senia I think it'd be helpful to others if you write it as an answer but I don't want to steal your answer. Do you mind writing it as an answer?

Comment: @SanghyunLee the goal of SO is to create a knowledge base together as community. So there is nothing wrong in "stealing" a link from 7 years old comment.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a vector of length `m` to a vector of length `n` (`len_n ++ len_m`) takes `O(m)`.

You can find the performance characteristics of each data structure on [this page](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html).